# How to display Dates (YYYY-MM-DD) on the x-axis of the graph resulting from the Rbeast algorithm?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using the Rbeast algorithm (Zhao et al. 2019) to identify regime breaks in a 128-day daily hydrometeorological series. In the graphical outputs, the x-axis displays either the day number in the time series (e.g. 0 to 128), or the dates in scalar scale (e.g. 2021.90 to 2022.25). I'd really like the dates to be displayed in "YYYY-MM-DD" format on the x axis. How can I achieve this?

For the moment, I've tried to enter the start of the time series (start = as.Date(2021-11-24)), the interval between data (deltat = "1day") and the period (period = "128 days").

```
out_Q <- beast(y = Q_All$X75e_percentile,
              start = as.Date('2021-11-24'), #commence quand
              deltat = "1day", #intervalle de temps entre 2 données ici 1 jour
              period = '128 days',
              season = 'none',
              quiet = TRUE)
```

```
plot.beast(out_Q,
           vars = c("t", "slpsgn"),
           ylab = c("Trend and breaking points", "Trend slope"),
           main = "",
           xlab = "Time",
           col = "red",
           ncpStat = "mean",
           xaxp = c(as.Date('2021-11-24'),as.Date('2022-03-31')))
```

Here's the result: [Scalat dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o4FJ.png)

[image]

I have also tried to remove these arguments and have thus obtained the day numbers.

Here's the result:[Number of the day in time serie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Rj4.png)

[image]